# url_for in flask: BuildError - could not build url for endpoint

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/test.css">
</head>
<body>
    {% for i in range(result['data']|length) %}
        <div id="wrapper">
        {% for key, value in result['data'][i].iteritems() %}
            <div id="first">{{ key }}</div>
            <div id="second"><a href="{{ url_for('employees_name', employee_id=value)}}">{{ value }}</a></div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        &nbsp;
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

When I pass "value" variable to "employee_id" I get an error:

> BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'employees_name'. Did you
>   forget to specify values ['employee_id']?

What's weird, when I pass "key" variable to "employee_id", there's everything alright but I need to pass "value" variable. What may cause the problem? Thanks!

Comment: What is the `@app.route()` registration for that endpoint?

Comment: Also, are you 100% certain it is **that `url_for()` call** that causes the build error? What happens if you remove that call temporarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my script and now it looks like this. It works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for i in range(result['data']|length) %}
            <div id="wrapper">
            {% for key, value in result['data'][i].iteritems() %}
                <div id="first">{{ key }}</div>
                <div id="second">{{ value }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div><a href="{{ url_for('employees_name', employee_id=result['data'][i]['EmployeeId'])}}">More</a></div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can test the code by hard-coding  the value for `employee_id` and test if that's the problem, i think your problem is that `{{ value }}` is empty.

since we don't have the code for `employees_name` view, i suggest you debug it like this:

- check the link with `href` empty, so you can see what `{{value}}` is and is it what you want passed to the view or not
- check what is the return of your loop over `result['data'][i]` and if that has any result at all
- i would check if there is `result['data']` at all by an `{% if result %}` to begin with

but again, hardcode the value for `employee_id` in `href` to see if problem is with `{{value}}` not being present or something other that that is causing the problem.

for instance, if `value` isn't the same type of variable you get in your `@app.route`, you could get this error.

Comment: `{{ value }}` is not empty.. that value is displayed in a browser.. and in url_for() I got that error.. but I've changed it to `result['data'][i]['EmployeeId']` and it works..